# Django Indentation error

Tags: python, django-views, indentation

I am new to Django and was trying this code in a tutorial. But now I'm not able to run my program because of the following error:

```
IndentationError at /
('unexpected indent', ('D:\\django_workspace\\django_bookmarks\\..\\django_bookmarks\\bookmarks\\views.py', 14, 4, '    return HttpResponse(output)\n'))
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Exception Type: IndentationError
Exception Value:    
('unexpected indent', ('D:\\django_workspace\\django_bookmarks\\..\\django_bookmarks\\bookmarks\\views.py', 14, 4, '    return HttpResponse(output)\n'))
Exception Location: D:\django_workspace\django_bookmarks\..\django_bookmarks\urls.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  C:\Python26\python.exe
Python Version: 2.6.4
Python Path:    ['D:\\django_workspace\\django_bookmarks', 'C:\\Python26', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python26\\lib', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 9 Mar 2010 19:18:32 +
```

My views.py file code is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

def main_page(request):
    template = get_template('main_page.html')
    variables = Context({
        'head_title': 'Django Bookmarks',
        'page_title': 'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
        'page_body': 'Where you can store and share bookmarks!'
})
output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)

def user_page(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        raise Http404('Requested user not found.')
        bookmarks = user.bookmark_set.all()
        template = get_template('user_page.html')
        variables = Context({
                'username': username,
                'bookmarks': bookmarks
})
output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Kindly help me rectify this problem! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely you're mixing tabs with spaces - use one or the other for your indenting... preferably spaces, according to this:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Just gotta love the way significant whitespace makes Python programs "more readable" ;-)

Answer (score -1):

First locate the line on which this error occurs. Delete the line entirely. Go to the end of the preceding line and then press enter. Now enter the line.