# Django dont accept new url

Tags: python, django

Good day,

I'm a absolut beginner with Python and Django. I'm following the book step of Nigel George and everything working fine until I try to add a url in the views.py to print Hello Word.

If Anybody can help me. I try different thing but I don't get it. It should be simple and work.  Thanks

**jre2** is my virtualenv and **jre_web** is my django site. I'm using django 1.8.13 for this book. I try django 2.1 and I have the same error.

Here the content of views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

And here the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from jre_web.views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('^hello/', hello),
]
```

Here the error I got.

> IndentationError at /
>
> unexpected indent (views.py, line 3)
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django
>   Version:  1.8.13 Exception Type:  IndentationError Exception Value:
>
> unexpected indent (views.py, line 3)
>
> Exception Location:   C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\jre_web\jre_web\urls.py in
>   , line 17 Python Executable:
>     C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\Scripts\python.exe Python Version:   3.7.2
>   Python Path:
>
> ['C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\jre_web', 
>   'C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\Scripts\python37.zip', 
>   'C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\DLLs',  'C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\lib', 
>   'C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\Scripts',  'c:\python\Lib', 
>   'c:\python\DLLs',  'C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2', 
>   'C:\Users\Minitaur\jre2\lib\site-packages']

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669725/8334374.

Comment: line 3 is `def hello(request):`. Make sure it's starting at the left and there isn't a space before `def`. Use an IDE that has specific python language support, i.e. a PEP-8 linter (or install a PEP-8 linter) so that it will show you these issues when typing.

Comment: Have you searched what "IndentationError" means and looked at your code at the place mentionned by the error message (views.py, line 3) ?

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick answer. Before I go to bed yesterday I realize that notepad++ might be not the best to edit code. I will use eclipse with pydev but for now I just want to learn the basic. I will check the space in my code when I'll go back home and probably try to use eclipse with PEP-8 to avoid beginner mistake. Cheers

Comment: Thanks again everybody, I make the '/hello' work yesterday but now I have a 404 Error on the main page. I'll figure it out and I'll review the code tonight. I played a lot in the code so I might just start from scratch.